# Use Mac OS X Terminal to copy files from remote computer to my desktop

Tags: macos, terminal, copy, command, scp

I'm trying to copy a file from a remote computer to my local desktop. The file is located at path `/Library/Application Support/EFI`.

In the Terminal, I ssh to the computer, type in `cd /` to get to the root directories, then I type the command in the following format:

```
scp username@hostname:Library/Application Support/EFI/[file name] /Users/[home directory]/Desktop
```

I keep getting the message, "No such file or directory."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may just need to escape the spaces with a backslash.  I.e. Application\ Support

Comment: This is a ***programming site***, this hasn't got anything to do with programming. Try asking your question on Super User.

Comment: Why are you sshing to the remote machine at all? Why don't you use `scp username@remotehost:/... ~/Desktop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the spaces in the path to the file.

An example follows:

```
scp user@host:"/home/user/my\\ directory/file" .
```

would copy the file from the following path on the server: /home/user/my directory/file to where you currently stand.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, the answer worked.

Sorry if I posted inappopriately.

Comment: @flux1968: Consider accepting the answer so to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you have spacing in a file name, in BSD, it doesn't like any spaces. So use a * after the first word. You should be good to go.

scp bubba@131.118.7.83:"/Users/bubba/Desktop/test*" .

Password:

test file.txt                     100% 1680KB  10.7MB/s   00:00